# Cannot parse with Realm database due to use of an apostrophe. - SWIFT

Tags: parsing, swift, apostrophe, realm

I'm querying a Realm database and all was good until I added an apostrophe to my job title.  The problem is with the following line of code:

```
var thisJob = Jobs.objectsWhere("jobTitle == '\(titleOfJob)'")
```

The above code works fine until I use an apostrophe in my job title. For example when I call my job "Tom's Job", the program crashes with the follow error.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "jobTitle == 'Tom's Job' "'
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the above by creating an identifier as a string of a NSDate and then using the date as a unique identifier to retrieve records rather than the job title which will be determined by the user's input!

```
var id:String = "\(NSDate())"
```

then

```
var thisJob = Jobs.objectsWhere("identifier == '\(identify)'")
```

Hope this helps anybody else with a similar issue!

Comment: You should use NSDate().description for your date description instead of "\(NSDate())"

Comment: Thanks for the tip Leonardo. Why is it better to use NSDate().description?

Comment: That's just conventions. exactly same results just one step less (String Interpolation) when running the app.

Comment: Hey Tom, you should also default to using NSPredicate since it handles these formatting issues.